# Crashed: com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader (com.apple.root.default-overcommit-priority)

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm getting the following crash report in Crashlytics: `Crashed: com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader (com.apple.root.default-overcommit-priority)` I've looked for a cause of the crash but can't seem to find one. Anyone that can give me some clarity in this?

Link: http://crashes.to/s/a14cc68b79f

Comment: The 7mb of free RAM is a bit suspicious. Does it do it if you restart your device?

Comment: Hi Daniel. Did you ever figure out how to get rid of this one?

Comment: I'm currently observing my crash logs after optimizing some memory management. The crashes seems to be gone. So my guess is that it was memory related. @holierthanthou84